# Make the if else statement in view yii2

Tags: php, view, tags, yii2

I have a problem in making if else statement in the view file in yii 2, the matter is the using of the

```
<p>
   <?php if(Yii::$app->user->can('create-car')){ ?>
        <?= Html::a('Tambah Mobil', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
   <?php}?>
</p>
```

When i run that code, it will show the end of file error, actually what's the matter with my code?

Comment: Could you show full code of this view?

Answer (score 3):

try

```
<p>
    <?php 
      if(Yii::$app->user->can('create-car')){ 
         echo  Html::a('Tambah Mobil', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']);
      } 
    ?>
</p>
```

Comment: If i run that code the button will dissappear, i guess it because we delete the <?= tag, howdy? and the result is :
Html::a('Tambah Mobil', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success'])

Answer (score 3):

You should do be able to do it like this

```
<?php if (Yii::$app->user->can('create-car')): ?>
                        <?= Html::a('Tambah Mobil', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
<?php else: ?>
                        <li>Your HTML to be rendered when condition is false</li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this:

```
<p>
   <?php if(Yii::$app->user->can('create-car')): ?>
       <?= Html::a('Tambah Mobil', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
   <?php else: ?>
       Else code here
   <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

Comment: This is an if statement, not an if else statement.

Comment: I've fixed the code of the author.
What a problem to add <?php else: ?>?

Answer (score -1):

Try this, i hope this will help you

```
<?php
        if(Yii::$app->user->can('admin'))
            { ?>
            <?= Html::a('Update', ['update', 'id' => $model->id], ['class' => 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
            <?= Html::a('Delete', ['delete', 'id' => $model->id], [
                'class' => 'btn btn-danger',
                'data' => [
                    'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete this item?',
                    'method' => 'post',
                ],
            ]) ?>
        <?php } ?>
```